# Ruby - Cannot open STDIN-pipe to .NET app

Tags: .net, ruby, pipe

I'm currently struggling with implementing a pipeline to any .NET program.
This started with me trying to hook my ruby script into a server console, and now I've already pinned this down to some fault with ruby. Right now I'm using a friends echo script.

Here's what I do:
Regular IO:

```rb
pipeline = IO.popen('Echo.exe', 'r+')
pipeline.gets
# => "Echo Program ready, enter some text:\n"
pipeline.print 'PLEASE REPLY'
pipeline.flush
pipeline.gets
# => (pry) output error: Interrupt (No output will ever come through here)
```

Open3 IO:

```rb
require 'open3'
pipeline = Open3::popen3('Echo.exe')
pipeline[1].gets
# => "Echo Program ready, enter some text:\n"
pipeline[0].print 'PLEASE'
pipeline[0].flush
pipeline[1].gets
# => (pry) output error: Interrupt (No output will ever come through here)
```

My friends echo script looks like this: (C#)

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Echo Program ready, enter some text:");
    string input;
    while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit") Console.WriteLine("Echo: " + input);
}
```

I've tried with regular IO pipes aswell, but they got the same issue. Do you have any ideas or advice?

Comment: It might be helpful to post the code that you've tried with regular IO pipes, since your friend's echo script is unknown to anyone here.

Comment: Gotcha, will do in a couple o mins.